# Attach document to email when it is selected by a user

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, email-attachments

I've been asked to make a program that selects a range of emails to send to, then a range to CC to, then attach a document/documents the user selects to the generated email.

I frankensteined this together from various tutorials.
It selects the email addresses and CCs, pulls the body paragraph from the text box, and includes the desired subject line.
I get the option to select the file but the email is generated with no attachment. Why isn't the selected file being attached to the email generated? Everything else is working fine.

```vb
Sub EmailAttachmentRecipients1()

    Dim xOutlook As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xCC As Range
    Dim xEmailAddr As String
    Dim xCCAddr As String
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCCRg As Range
    Dim Myfile As FileDialog
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSelItem As Variant

    Set Myfile = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    Dim FileAddress As String
  
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the addresses list:", "Please select", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailItem = xOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
            If xEmailAddr = "" Then
                xEmailAddr = xCell.Value
            Else
                xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xCCRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the CC list:", "Please select", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xCCRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each xCC In xCCRg
        If xCC.Value Like "*@*" Then
            If xCCAddr = "" Then
                xCCAddr = xCC.Value
            Else
                xCCAddr = xCCAddr & ";" & xCC.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    With xMailItem
        xFileDlg.InitialFileName = "initial file path goes here but I have removed it" 
        With Myfile
            .Filters.Clear
            .Title = "Please select a file to add"
            .Show
        End With
    
        .To = xEmailAddr
        .CC = xCCAddr
        .Subject = "This is a sample subject line" 
        .Body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes(1).Text
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        Set xMailItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

        For Each xSelItem In xFileDlg.SelectedItems
            xMailItem.Attachments.Add xSelItem
        Next

        FileAddress = .SelectedItems(1)
        .Attachments.Add = .SelectedItems(1)
        .Display
    End With
    Set xOutlook = Nothing
    Set xMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider `On Error GoTo 0` to be mandatory after `On Error Resume Next`. [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) Add `On Error GoTo 0` immediately before `If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`. Update the post with this line added. **If** there is an error add the description and the line with the error to the post.

Comment: Is there a particular problem in your code that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi @niton thank you for the suggestion. I have added the line and updated the code in my request. It produced Run-time error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Hi Dmitry, I need the selected document to be attached to the email that is generated and it is not being attached. I have clarified my request above. Thank you!

Comment: To debug press F5 until you get to the line with the error. Likely `xFileDlg.InitialFileName =`.  You have to `Set xFileDlg`. Replace all occurrences of `Myfile` with `xFileDlg` then move on to the other errors.

Comment: Nesting can work but I suggest you separate the `With xMailItem` and `With xFileDlg` blocks. Apply all of the  `With xFileDlg` first. You have placed an `xFileDlg` line in the wrong block.

Comment: @niton I made the change you recommended and the one below (changing ".Attachments.Add = .SelectedItems(1)" to ".Attachments.Add .SelectedItems(1)"). I do not know how to denest the With xMailItem and With xFileDlg - should I just remove all of the With xMailItem ones and try again?

I currently have run-time error 438 on line ".AllowMultiSelect = True" Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Move`.AllowMultiSelect = True` from the `Withx MailItem` block into the `With xFileDlg` block.

Comment: @niton The solution you posted worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`With` blocks separated for simplicity but not necessary.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant

Sub EmailAttachmentRecipients2()

    Dim xOutlook As Object
    Dim xMailItem As Object
    
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    
    Dim xCC As Range
    Dim xEmailAddr As String
    Dim xCCAddr As String
    
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xCCRg As Range
    
    Dim xFileDlg As FileDialog
    Dim xSelItem As Variant

    Set xFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
        
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the addresses list:", "Please select", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Consider mandatory to closely follow On Error Resume Next
    
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set xOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailItem = xOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If xCell.Value Like "*@*" Then
            If xEmailAddr = "" Then
                xEmailAddr = xCell.Value
            Else
                xEmailAddr = xEmailAddr & ";" & xCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xCCRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the CC list:", "Please select", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xCCRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each xCC In xCCRg
        If xCC.Value Like "*@*" Then
            If xCCAddr = "" Then
                xCCAddr = xCC.Value
            Else
                xCCAddr = xCCAddr & ";" & xCC.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    With xFileDlg
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Please select a file to add"
        'xFileDlg.InitialFileName = "initial file path goes here but I have removed it"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show
            
        For Each xSelItem In .SelectedItems
            xMailItem.Attachments.Add xSelItem
        Next
    End With
        
    With xMailItem
        .To = xEmailAddr
        .CC = xCCAddr
        .Subject = "This is a sample subject line"
        '.Body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes(1).Text
        .Body = "Test"
        .Display
    End With
    
    Set xOutlook = Nothing
    Set xMailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
.Attachments.Add = .SelectedItems(1)
```

is wrong. Did you mean the following?

```
.Attachments.Add .SelectedItems(1)
```